# How to get all the telegram from server in socket programming when the number of frames and the length of each frame is not fixed?

Tags: java, sockets

this is my first question and Eng is not my mother language. If I did not description clearly, please let me know.

Background: In IEC104 electrical communication protocol, when the client request once, the server maybe responds with more than one frames of telegram in one tcp socket package. All the frames are started with "68" then the length of telegram. 
For example:
client: 68 14 00 00 00 00 67 01 **06** 00 01 00 00 00 00 1C 79 BA 0B AE 04 11 //time synchronization activation.
server: 68 14 00 00 00 00 67 01 **07** 00 01 00 00 00 00 1C 79 BA 0B AE 04 11 //time synchronization confirmation, this is the expected response. 
But there are situations that the server reply other telegram before time synchronization confirmation.
For example below is the mass telegram(from server):  `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` ah~  sorry for that long....

There are eight "68",i.e., it comprise 8 frames of telegram.
 in this case i have a question in collecting the telegram from server. As I mentioned above, I don't know how many frames of telegram and the length of each frame, so I defined big array byte[2048] to contain all the telegram then split it to 11 strings (new String[11]). This works in most situation but obviously it is not well designed.

```
 byte[] boTimeSync = HexStrToByte.hexStringToBytes(Setting.TIMESYNC);
            out.write(boTimeSync);
            out.flush(); 
            VisibleFrame.updateTextArea(Setting.TIMESYNC.toUpperCase()+"\n");
            VisibleFrame.updateTextArea(TimeParsing.parsing(Setting.TIMESYNC.toUpperCase())+"\n");
            byte[] biTimeSync = new byte[2048];         
            bin.read(biTimeSync);
            str = t104.ByteToStr.byteToStr(biTimeSync);
            String[] bi = new String[11]; 
            bi = SplitTele.splitTele(str);
```

Then how to get all the frames since the InputStream.available() is not suitable in network programming?

Comment: I don't get it: why are you not simply doing: `if (str.substring(0, 2).equals("68") && len_current <= len) {`

Comment: Thank you. I think len_current <= len is always true and this is not the sufficient condition to asume a correct frame.

Comment: Well, i think i get the point: && has higher priority than ?: operator.

Comment: Is there any way to know that a frame is the last frame in the response to a particular request? What is the workflow, is it request-response or are frames sent to server independent of the frames received from server?

Comment: @Arkadiy This is my first time to use stackoverflow and i don't know whether you can receive this message in this way. The answer to your question: There is no way to tell the last frame as far as I know; It's request-response, but maybe there's buffered indication in server and the indication will be sent to client when client request some other types of information. My intention is, to get and classify all the frames from server until i get what client requests, then client sends further request.

Comment: If the length of `frame` is returned in the resoponse then as the answer suggests, you need to write a wrapper around `read` method that checks for `68`, reads the next byte (i.e. length), reads `length` bytes and returns.

Comment: I am novice at JAVA. what does the 'wrapper' mean here? Something like a callable function as in C or C++ language? or Interface Wrapper in JAVA?  I get the intention of the answer by @EJP, but I don't know how to call the code snippet and break from it to get one message, parse it, output it then go to the next message, till all the message packaged in one frames is parsed. Now i can only get the very first message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `DataInputStream`:

```
int start;
do
{
    start = din.read();
} while (start != -1 && start != 0x68);
if (start == -1)
    throw new EOFException();
int length = din.readUnsignedByte();
byte[] message = new byte[length];
din.readFully(message);
return message;
```

There is no solution to 'find the last frame in response to a particular request', unless the response contains a request ID of some kind.

Comment: You opened a window for my by checking the byte in stream. I always thought to convert the stream to string and check the length. But I don't follow you. What's the purpose of the do...while loop? All bytes in stream are read but not stored? From API, I learn readByte() 'Reads and returns one input byte' (range -128 through 127). Why is this the length of one frame?

Comment: The purpose of the do/while loop is to ensure you synchronize at the start of a new frame. It's the length of one frame because that's what your samples indicate. If the length word is longer, use a different `readXXX()` method as appropriate.

Comment: I'll describe my understanding here: Take the telegram in my question for example. First, '68' is neglected, then we get '0E'(14 in dec), which is the length of the first frame(actually the length is 16, 14 + "68".length() + "0E".length()). The variant 'start' is 14 now but we do nothing to 'start', we get '00' then '00'...until the end of the telegram(2048 in length, all "68" is neglected). The readUnsignedByte() is not in the loop, so it get 0x68. Please correct me where I am wrong. 
And in this way I think we only get the first frame. How to buffer all the frames?

Comment: No. Completely wrong in every respect. 68 is in hex. It is not a quoted string. The `readUnsignedByte()` is not in the loop, which had terminated when 0x68 has *already* been read, so it gets 0x14, the length word, which is why it gets stored into a variable named `length`. We then read exactly `length` bytes, whatever `length` was, in this case 14, which gives us the first frame. There is no 2048 here.

Comment: ah~yes, suddenly i realized I took the `while` condition wrongly. It was easy :(.Then how to handle it that we should store all the frames in one socket package to several byte array? We don't know the number of frames. If we interpret the frame one by one, is it possible that the server sends new frames before client manages to interpret the current one?

Comment: Of course it's possible. And I've already said there is no general solution to 'find the last frame'. If the protocol is as you described, you just have to process a frame at a time.

Comment: Well, does this means that maybe we will miss certain frame(s)?
This is my first time to use stackoverflow, you make me enjoy this website, although there's time zone gap.
Thank you very much.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean you will miss anything, if has been sent correctly. Have you *tried* this code, or are you just going to ask questions about it forever?

Comment: I'm sorry I hadn't tried it before, for I had to use the device in my work. I only can use in spare time for interest (verifying the code). I managed to try it today, and got only the first information in the data packet(which comprises 9 pieces of information). I don't know how to post pictures or attachments to illustrate it. Outside your code snap, it there another loop?

Comment: That's what I said above. This code delivers one frame at a time. You need to *keep calling it.* I am finding the level of incomprehension displayed here really surprising.

Comment: Not exactly. I am quite a novice at the language and started to learn it last month. I think most people here are well armed with the language.

Comment: It's not just Java. I find I am repeating myself constantly, which I dislike intensely, and that quite simple concepts are not being understood.

Comment: I am back to you after hours of reworking on your code and no gains. I think I understand the method read() wrongly( when returns -1). I notice you mentioned several times in others posts that -1 is returned when socket is closed, isn't it? Could you please take several minutes to have a glance of my new questions here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43818979/where-is-the-end-of-stream-in-java-socketwhen-datainputstream-read-returns]

Comment: Why? Nothing has changed. Your new code doesn't appear to have benefited from my assistance in any way. You either need to use this code or correct/clarify the definition of your application protocol. As stated, this code should work.

Comment: Maybe, but as your mentioned I should *keep calling* this code snippet, this is the point. I have no idea when to call it and when to break. Based on my understanding descripted in another post(which you say is wrong), I tried to *call* your code to deliver ONLY one message once and keep doing this unitl all the message (more than one are packaged in one frame) are delivered(In my incorrect understanding, -1 being returned means the end FRAME). I found this didn't work, so I made that simple code snippet to check whether the End Of Frame would return -1.Then I raised that question.

Comment: based on your code snippet, I want to break the loop by checking the value in.available(). The server is always on my desk, so I assume the connection is stable.
'cnt = 0;
total = 0;
while((total = in.available()) == 0){
 Timer t = new Timer();                   
 t.schedule(new TimerTask(){                    
  public void run(){}                    
 }, 0,100);
}
while(cnt < total){ 
  byte[] biTS = stackof(in);
  str = t104.ByteToStr.byteToStr(biTS);
  if(str.substring(12, 14).equals("67")){...//all message is parsed here 
  }
 }'

Comment: This is the method you provided, and I made some change:
'public static byte[] stackof(DataInputStream in) throws IOException{
   int length = in.readUnsignedByte();
   byte[] message = new byte[length+2];
   message[0]=(byte)0x68;message[1] = (byte)length;
   in.readFully(message,2,length);
   cnt += (length+2);
   return message;
    }'
 It seems to work ok till now.
 Does this make sense?