# Where is the 'End' Of Stream in JAVA socket(when DataInputStream.read() returns -1)? The connection colsed, or just one frame is finished?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm confused by DataInputStream.read() method which is explained "If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned. " in javadoc/api. With my following code snippet and telegram captured by wireshark, I expected to get "1042000001031640100002829130231911299"(in frame 9) however "104200000103164010000282913023191129910441020"(in frame 9 AND frame 19) is what I got:

```
int a = 0;
while(( a = in.read())!= -1){
System.out.print(a);
}
```

**Timesync response**

[image: Timesync response]

**Supervisory**

[image: Timesync response]

In my understanding, when frame 9 ends, we 'reach the end of stream', so we get 1042000001031640100002829130231911299(in dec, while in wireshark it's in hex). But it seems we 'reach the end of stream' when socket is closed. 
Then how to get only the data in frame 9 (I'll store it in a byte array)? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) the javadoc for `read()`, this is what it says:

> If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been
>   reached, the value -1 is returned.

So, in your case, end of `frame` does not mean end of stream as there are more frames into the `stream` (yes, end of stream means all the data is transmitted).

If you want to read the data for one frame then you can use overloaded version of `read`, e.g.:

```
public int read(byte[] b) throws IOException

public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException
```

However, these methods might not read all the bytes. If you know the `length` of a frame then you can write a wrapper around `read()` and perform an action every time `length` bytes are read.

Comment: **If you know the length of a frame then  ** well, this is the problem. Could you please take a glance at my another question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610958/how-to-get-all-the-telegram-from-server-in-socket-programming-when-the-number-of/43621558?noredirect=1#comment74443443_43621558]

Comment: @xin Make up your mind. The question in your duplicate link asserts that you *do* know the length of a frame, and clear asserts which byte it is in.

Comment: @EJP Not exactly. I know the length for any ASDU(application service data unit, an item in electrical protocol,which is illustrated in attached picture), however, different ASDU are with different length. and the Server will not send the ASDUs in fixed order(for example, there are some types of information buffered in the Server for this time and other types for next time or no buffered information). Besides, it's not fixed how much message will be packaged in one frame. Now I have no idea how to split the message in one frame except the unskillful way to store it in a BIG array then split it.

Comment: So you need to learn more about the application protocol. It must be parseable by an application without relying on non-existent magical properties of the sockets API.

Comment: Workflow: Step1, Client sends STARTDT activation, server responds with STARTDT confirmation; Step2,Client sends TimeSynchronization activation, server responds with variable types of information(if there 's buffered information in the server) in variable frames. TimeSynchronization Confirmation is one of them; Step3, Client send STOPDT activation, server responds with STOPDT confirmation. Now I am hung in step2 and cannot find a way to jump to step3. Based on this can you provide more code than last time? I think this is easier for you to explain and for me to understand, isn't it ?@EJP

Answer (score 1):

The notion of *frames* or *packets* is a physical, low-level notion of the network protocol.

You can't choose how sent bytes are grouped in packets, and you can't get a given number of packets. Only a continuous stream of bytes.

You need an application-level protocol on top of TCP to distinguish your functional messages. They could be lines of text ended with a newline character, or a number of bytes N followed by N bytes, or something like that.

Comment: He has frames in his application protocol. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

> In my understanding, when frame 9 ends, we 'reach the end of stream

Your understanding is entirely incorrect. End of a frame is not end of stream. End of stream on a socket means the peer has closed the connection.

If you want to read fixed length frames, see `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

Comment: Currently I only want to parse the time synchronization information, whose length is 0x14, but I need to read all the frames return from Server for future extension. Different types of information are with different length, and in this protocol we cannot foresee which type of information is the next one from Server.
Add I don't agree with your comment that this is a exact duplicate of another post. This one is more detailed for only a small part of that one. Besides, I add pictures to make my questions understood easily.

Comment: We've already been over and over this in your previous question. You need to keep reading frames. There is no way to identity the last frame for a sent message from the information you've provided. Maybe there is something about the frame format you've missed. The length of a frame is given in the frame, according to your own information. You can then read the frame, and I gave you code to do so. `read()` does not magically return -1 at the end of all the frames. This is a duplicate. The place to provide more information was in the original question.

Comment: *The length of a frame is given in the frame*  No, since there are maybe variable pieces of message packaged in one frame. You may refer to my 'duplicate' post where the long string (ignore the meaningless zeroes in the end) is from ONE frame, time sync confirmation is in the 2nd place(starts with 6814). There are restrictiones to edit the original question,e.g., I cannot insert more than 2 picture links. Does this rule mean I can ask questiones in one respect only in one post? I appreciate what you did but I think you were a little over the top.